# How to solve a Duplicate file exception in android?

Tags: android, json, firebase-realtime-database

I am  trying to make a chat application using `Firebase`. The code seems to be fine but I am getting a strange error while trying to run the project.

Here is the error:

```
Error:FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
Execution failed for task ':app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException:com.android.builder.packaging.DuplicateFileException: Duplicate files copied in APK META-INF/LICENSE
File1: C:\Users\Aadesh\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.fasterxml.jackson.core\jackson-annotations\2.2.2\285cb9c666f0f0f3dd8a1be04e1f457eb7b15113\jackson-annotations-2.2.2.jar
File2: C:\Users\Aadesh\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.fasterxml.jackson.core\jackson-databind\2.2.2\3c8f6018eaa72d43b261181e801e6f8676c16ef6\jackson-databind-2.2.2.jar
File3: C:\Users\Aadesh\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.fasterxml.jackson.core\jackson-core\2.2.2\d20be6a5ddd6f8cfd36ebf6dea329873a1c41f1b\jackson-core-2.2.2.jar


* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --debug option to get more log output.
```

What could be the problem and how do i solve this?

Gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 24
buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.aadesh.chatnow"
    minSdkVersion 17
    targetSdkVersion 24
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.5.2'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: have you run with --debug and/or --stacktrace?

Comment: yes it gives the same error

Comment: you are repeating these libs perhaps in different gradle files. they are occurring more than once.

Comment: i have added my gradle file. I checked it but i couldnt find any duplications.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should add:

```
 android {
     packagingOptions { 
         exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
         exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
         exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
         exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
     }
 }
```

to your `build.gradle` file. this will skip those files while merging libs.

Comment: If we skip these files what effect will it have on the app?

Comment: none, as those files don't contain any code. those are just licenses and notices for distribution.

Comment: What a simple solution.  Thank you very much.